# Java Hiding: Any Way for Client Classes to Call `super`?

Tags: c#, java, syntax, overriding, hide

Aside from adding a method explicitly on the subclass to call a `super` method, is there anyway to "unhide" it temporarily? I would like to call the `super.blah()` method on a `Test2` instance. Must I use a method like `originalBlah`, or is there another way?

```
public class TestingHiding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 b = new Test2();
        b.blah();
    }
}

class Test2 extends Test1 {
    public void blah() {
        System.out.println("test2 says blah");
    }

    public void originalBlah() {
        super.blah();
    }
}

class Test1 {
    public void blah() {
        System.out.println("test1 says blah");
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Sorry to add to the question late in the game, but I had a memory flash (I think): in C# is this different? That it depends on which class you `think` you have (Test1 or Test2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to do something like `Test1 b = new Test2(); b.super.blah()`. This cannot be done, super is strictly limited to calling from inside the subclass to the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to subvert the concept of inheritance like that.

Comment: +1. If you find that you want to do things like that, then maybe you should look at object composition instead of subclassing, which offers more flexibility to the client code.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo. I generally avoid subclassing altogether and prefer 'has a' to 'is a' relationships. But this case came up, just wanted to know if Java provides for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to imagine situation when you need thing like this.

You can forbid method overriding.
Also you can consider [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern technique.

Comment: Isn't the `template method` just polymorphism by a different name?

Comment: @yar: Yes and no, `template method` is the name of the pattern where each implementation differ only by some really minute detail and thus don't really need that much extra/override code to do their job. As always, Wikipedia's example is a bit confusing, check these two links for more info: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TemplateMethod http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=164

Comment: @Esko, thanks again for that. I see now that the hook method -- template method -- is what I use all the time to give API clients a concrete implementation. Now I know what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is : you can't

you could have blah be

```
class Test2 extends Test1 {
    public void blah() {
        if("condition"){
            super.blah()
        }
        System.out.println("test2 says blah");
    }

}
```

or go the originalBlah way, or decouple the blah implementation altogether to be able to call whichever implementation you need but that's about it.